# external harddrive for sample library storage -and- audio editing

Tags: harddrive, storage, sound-library

hello,

as my independent sample library keeps growing bigger and bigger, i'm running out of space and looking for a reliable storage solution. since a Macbook Pro is my main computer i'm after an external desktop harddrive, which i would also like to use for live sound editing. therefore it needs to be fast, reliable, with falseness reputation. should have USB2.0, Firewire400/800, eSata is a plus. 2TB is enough. my limited budget narrowed me down to the WD My Book Studio Edition II:

http://www.wdc.com/en/products/Products.asp?DriveID=621

does anyone have experience working with this one? or can anyone suggest a better alternative?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my SFX on earlier model of WD Studio Edition. Never had any problems with it. I recommend you to buy it.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a couple of those fail on me. I was able to pull the drives and the data was safe. It was the enclosure that failed. Check out Other World Computing. I've never, ever had a failure on anything I've purchased from them. Great stuff. I use one as my main editing drive connected via FW800 and another as my SFX drive.

http://www.macsales.com/

Comment: I've had the same experience as Jason: OWC rocks in every way.

Answer (score 1):

Any hard drive carries a risk of crashing and the potential loss of your data. One option that is slightly out of your budget, but still affordable and much more reliable is a [Drobo](http://www.drobo.com/products/index.php). Using the BeyondRAID technology, a Drobo system will always safeguard your data as long as there is more than one drive in the unit. A lot of people working in digital media are using these. Check the vid to see more on how they work.

[youtube]05yqvb5n36M[/youtube]

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05yqvb5n36M

Comment: Don't forget that you can also make your own RAID with software and two matched-size harddrives. Mirrored RAIDs have saved my bacon multiple times over the years, and striped RAIDs are fast, baby!

Comment: @NoiseJockey Have you used FreeNAS before? I've heard that it's a genuine rival to the commercial options like the Drobo, but I don't know anyone who's actually trialled it.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeNAS

Comment: @Colin Impressive piece of kit, bit pricey for me too. Would like to RAID my harddrives but haven't got a clue how to.

Answer (score 0):

We're using a 2TB LaCie 2big quadra (well, it's 4TB but a RAID). The first that drive arrived busted, but customer service was impressive and they sent me a replacement immediately. The only beef is that the fan is pretty loud, but most of our drives are.  Anyone have a cost-effective solution for noisy drives?